# Stacked percentage barplot with two factors

Tags: r, ggplot2, bar-chart, percentage, stacked

I have a dataset where every datapoint is either "yes" or "no" for variable1, and either 1-2-3-4 for another factor (categorical) called "round". I would like to plot the rate of "yes" and "no" per round 1 through 4 on a stacked barplot where the columns show percentages, not freqs. For some reason this seems very complicated. I have tried multiple things with ggplot but I can't get it to show my proportions in y, I'm probably missing something with "count".

I'm also open to working directly with a dataframe that would show the proportions (as follows), but I'd rather be able to do it directly from the original dataframe:
1 - 12.11% yes
2 - 14.02% yes
3 - 26.59% yes
4 - 34.09% yes

Any tips will be greatly appreciated! Thank you

Comment: Welcome to SO! It would be easier to help you if you provide [a minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) including the code you have tried and a snippet of your data or some fake data. But it's actually hard to believe that this question hasn't been answered before. See e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66631575/ggplot-stacked-bar-plot-with-percentage-labels for one approach to compute the percentages manually.

Comment: Many thanks, the link you sent had the solution!

Comment: Greetings! It would be helpful to have a minimal reproducible dataset included in your question. One way of doing that is by using the `dput` command. You can find out how to do this here: https://youtu.be/3EID3P1oisg